# Calculating sum of column of 10 days from activity date

Tags: python, pandas

I tried looking for the answer for my question but can not find exactly what I'm looking for. I have revenue for a customer and product by day(each customer does not have rev per product each day) and am looking to know the 10 days revenue prior and post of that activity date for that customer, product

Current Input

| customer | product | activity_date | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | product a | 2022-01-04 | 45.24 |
| 89 | product b | 2021-06-17 | 9294.21 |
| 35 | product a | 2020-05-20 | 75.12 |

Expected Output

| customer | product | activity_date | revenue | rev_10_d_prior | rev_10_d_post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | product a | 2022-01-04 | 45.24 |  |  |
| 89 | product b | 2021-06-17 | 9294.21 |  |  |
| 35 | product a | 2020-05-20 | 75.12 |  |  |

Comment: you should provide a minimal reproducible example (input and expected output)

Comment: Is your table stored in a pandas dataframe? Do you need to group by pair (customer, product)? Do you need the sum of the revenue?

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti Yes the data is stored in a pandas dataframe. I am looking for the group by pairs, so ie the sum of the 10 days to 2022-01-04 prior rev for customer 43 and product a

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add 2 new columns to your dataframe

```
  dataframe.insert(4,'rev_10_d_prior','')
  dataframe.insert(5,'rev_10_d_post','')
```

Comment: I doubt this is what OP expects ;)

Comment: I don't need columns added, I need assistance with calculating the outputs, haha

Comment: Ok Sorry i thought you wanted to add columns

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your dataframe and the column `activity_date` is a `datetime` column (sorted) then you could try to use [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df["rev_10_d_prior"] = (
    df.groupby(["customer", "product"], as_index=False)
      .rolling("10D", on="activity_date", closed="left").sum()
      .revenue
)

df["rev_10_d_post"] = (
    df[::-1].groupby(["customer", "product"], as_index=False)
            .rolling("10D", on="activity_date", closed="left").sum()
            .revenue[::-1]
)
```